# mysql group_concat returns null row if one entry in the group is null

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

I have a rather simple query which looks to combine all results from another table into one json object.

**MySQL**

```
SELECT s.id, s.uid, s.sexnumber, s.rating, s.sextime, s.diary, GROUP_CONCAT(p.pid,',') as positions, GROUP_CONCAT(w.id,':',w.who) as who, GROUP_CONCAT('{',
        '\"lat\":',l.lat,
        ',\"lon\":',l.lon,
        ',\"house\":',l.house,
        ',\"house_number\":',l.house_number,
        ',\"road\":',l.road,
        ',\"supermarket\":',l.supermarket,
        ',\"city\":',l.city,
        ',\"city_district\":',l.city_district,
        ',\"country\":',l.country,
        ',\"country_code\":',l.country_code,
        ',\"county\":',l.county,
        ',\"neighbourhood\":',l.neighbourhood,
        ',\"pedestrian\":',l.pedestrian,
        ',\"place_of_worship\":',l.place_of_worship,
        ',\"postcode\":',l.postcode,
        ',\"state\":',l.state,
        ',\"suburb\":',l.suburb,
        '}'
    ) as location, GROUP_CONCAT(ww.id,':',ww.name) as place
    FROM users u join sex s
     on s.uid = u.uid
     LEFT OUTER JOIN whos ws
     ON s.id = ws.sid
     LEFT OUTER JOIN who w
     ON w.id = ws.wid
     LEFT OUTER JOIN locations l
     ON l.sid = s.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN wheresex whs
     ON whs.sid = s.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN wherewhere ww
     ON whs.wid = ww.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN positions p
     ON s.id = p.sid
    WHERE u.sessionCheck = '%s'
    GROUP BY s.id
    ORDER BY s.sextime DESC;
```

If any of the `location` results inside the `GROUP_CONCAT` are `NULL` then the entire entry will return `NULL`.

How can I have the individual results that are `NULL` return this way and anything else with their values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must admit that I haven't tried to execute this sort of query before, but I can't see how a coalesce wouldn't do the trick?

```
SELECT s.id, s.uid, s.sexnumber, s.rating, s.sextime, s.diary, GROUP_CONCAT(p.pid,',') as positions, GROUP_CONCAT(w.id,':',w.who) as who, GROUP_CONCAT('{',
        '\"lat\":',coalesce(l.lat,'Unknown'),
        ',\"lon\":',coalesce(l.lon,'Unknown'),
        ',\"house\":',coalesce(l.house,'Unknown'),
        ',\"house_number\":',coalesce(l.house_number,'Unknown'),
        ',\"road\":',coalesce(l.road,'Unknown'),
        ',\"supermarket\":',coalesce(l.supermarket,'Unknown'),
        ',\"city\":',coalesce(l.city,'Unknown'),
        ',\"city_district\":',coalesce(l.city_district,'Unknown'),
        ',\"country\":',coalesce(l.country,'Unknown'),
        ',\"country_code\":',coalesce(l.country_code,'Unknown'),
        ',\"county\":',coalesce(l.county,'Unknown'),
        ',\"neighbourhood\":',coalesce(l.neighbourhood,'Unknown'),
        ',\"pedestrian\":'coalesce(,l.pedestrian,'Unknown'),
        ',\"place_of_worship\":',coalesce(l.place_of_worship,'Unknown'),
        ',\"postcode\":',coalesce(l.postcode,'Unknown'),
        ',\"state\":',coalesce(l.state,'Unknown'),
        ',\"suburb\":',coalesce(l.suburb,'Unknown'),
        '}'
    ) as location, GROUP_CONCAT(ww.id,':',ww.name) as place
```

Edit: I am not sure if I understand your comment correctly, but if you want to add quotes around the values returned by the coalesce you could use a [concat function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) like this:

```
'\"lat\":',concat('"',coalesce(l.lat,'Unknown'),'"')
```

Comment: Good stuff, everything returned correctly. While I've got you here, is there way to add `"` before and adter the result inside the coalesce? I assume not: `coalesce(\"l.lat\",'null')` will give me back `\"l.lat\"` Which makes sense

Comment: Awesome, thanks. The idea is exactly what I want, but would there be any way to keep the `Unknown` out of the `\"\"`. Currently with this, the returned result will always have quotation marks. I'd only like results that are not null to have the quotes.

Comment: Its fine now, I'm just going to use a simple string replace in php to remove the `"` from the null values. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You maybe looking for [`Concat`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-concat-function.htm) not [`Group_Concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
   CONCAT(w.id,':',w.who)
```

and same for

```
  CONCAT('{',
    '\"lat\":',l.lat,
    ',\"lon\":',l.lo
```

Comment: So far fluffeh's answer worked... but maybe I'll need urs anyway

Comment: CONCAT for me, in the location part of the query will wrap each time with `{` Basically starting the entire thing for each row I am trying to merge.